# Diccionarios anidados a partir de listas en Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

tengo un texto del cual cree una lista para cada una de sus frases, es algo asi:

`listas = [['Alan', 'aime', 'Béatrice', '.'], ['Connor', 'aime', 'Delilah', '.']]`

Entonces cada frase es una lista y todo a su vez esta dentro de otra lista. De esas listas debo crear un diccionario que a su vez contenga otros. Debo tambien contar la cantidad de veces que se encuentra una palabra delante de la anterior. El resultado que debo obtener es este

```
{ '': {'Alan': 1, 'Connor': 1},
 'Alan': {'aime': 1},
 'aime': {'Béatrice': 1, 'Delilah': 1},
 'Béatrice': {'.': 1},
 'Connor': {'aime': 1},
 'Delilah': {'.': 1}}
```

Es decir, delante de Alan y Connor no hay nada.

Luego delante de 'aime', se encuentra Alan 1 vez y Connor 1 vez

Béatrice y Delilah tienen 'aime' por delante una vez cada una de ellas. Y así...

Entonces no tengo ni idea de como manejar el asunto cuando delante de la palabra no hay nada, caso de Alan y Connor, luego no logro que cuente las palabras, en fin... mi programa no funciona para nada. Tengo apenas esto:

```
diccionario = {}

for i in range(len(listas)):
    for j in range(len(listas)):
        temp = listas[i][j]
        if temp not in diccionario:
            diccionario [temp] = 0
        else:
            diccionario [temp] += 1
        
print(diccionario)
```

Esta es la salida que tengo:
`{'Alan': 0, 'aime': 1, 'Connor': 0}`

Gracias de antemano, estoy empezando por lo que agradezco infinitamente su ayuda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es posible utilizar [**`Counter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.Counter) y [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) del módulo [**`collections`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#module-collections) para conseguir el resultado deseado:

1. Importa las clases necesarias arriba mencionadas:

   ```py
   from collections import Counter, defaultdict
   ```
2. Define una lista de listas con las oraciones *«tokenizadas»* a analizar:

   ```py
   oraciones = [
       ['Alan', 'aime', 'Béatrice', '.'],
       ['Connor', 'aime', 'Delilah', '.']
   ]
   ```
3. Utiliza `Counter` para contar el número de veces que aparece cada pareja de palabras:

   ```py
   frecuencias = Counter(
       pareja_de_elementos
       for oración in oraciones
       for pareja_de_elementos in zip([''] +  oración, oración)
   )
   ```

   Los dos bucles `for` utilizados forman parte de una [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), que tiene una sintaxis y un efecto similar a las, quizá más populares, [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions): por cada oración en la lista de oraciones, recorre cada pareja de elementos *(tokens)*, tomando en su primera iteración una cadena vacía junto al primer elemento.

   Analizando más de cerca la forma de generar las parejas de elementos:

   - `[''] + oración` añade una cadena de caracteres vacía al comienzo de cada lista de *tokens* de una oración, de modo que `['Alan', 'aime', ···]` se convierte en  `['', 'Alan', 'aime', ···]`.
   - Una vez hecho esto, [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) podrá recorrer todos los pares de *token* avanzando de uno en uno; por ejemplo `(("", "Alan"), ("Alan", "aime"), ···)` para la lista anteriormente mostrada.

     La función `zip` toma uno o más *iterables*, como pueden serlo las listas, y devuelve grupos tomando un elemento de cada lista. Por ejemplo, `zip((1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7))` devolvería primero un grupo con los primeros elementos de cada lista, después los segundos y así hasta llegar al último elemento de la lista más corta; `((1, 4, 6), (2, 5, 7))`.
4. Una vez hecho esto, `frecuencias` contendrá un objeto del tipo `Counter` con una estructura similar a la de un diccionario: `{("", "Alan"): 1, ("Alan", "aime"): 1, ···}`. Ahora es el momento de convertir los datos al formato especificado en la pregunta:

   ```py
   resultado = defaultdict(dict)
   for pareja, veces in frecuencias.items():
       resultado[pareja[0]].update({pareja[1]: veces})
   ```

   La variable `resultado`, del tipo `defaultdict(dict)` comenzará siendo como un diccionario normal, con la salvedad de que, al intentar acceder a un objeto inexistente, siempre encontraremos un `dict` (o el tipo que especifiquemos) en vez de un error.